# What does mean Thread 0x7fffc57fa700 (LWP 31671) exited] in gdb?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, gdb

I develop and debug some program on Ubuntu 18.04 using C and C++.
At some point my multithreaded program crashes. In gdb I also see:

```
Thread 0x7fffc57fa700 (LWP 31671) exited]
```

What means 0x7fffc57fa700 and LWP 31671 ? I guess it is something like thread id. I need get it in C code. But when I tried `std::this_thread::get_id()` it returned int value, not 0x7fffc57fa700.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*LWP 31671*" is the "Light Weight" process ID of the thread which ended. It  inside the Linux kernel represents the thread. It's an implementation detail appearing on Linux, just ignore it.

"*0x7fffc57fa700*" is the hexadecimal representation of the thread's ID, namely what is return be the thread class' member function `get_id()` for C/C++ threads or `pthread_self()` for POSIX threads.

Answer (score 0):

Address probably refers to either pthread_t (can be obtained with `pthread_self`) or to thread entry point, while LWP ( Light Weight Process) id can be obtained with `syscall(SYS_gettid)`.

Note that the value returned by `this_thread::get_id()` is not necessary related to those system values, it is just an identifier with different values among all the thread objects representing a running thread that can be used to distinguish between threads.